# Spring double SessionManagement in application

Tags: spring, spring-security, token, jsessionid

I have application with `@Controller` for web-view and `@RestController` for api layer.

Controller layer needs session, using cookies with `JSESSIONID`.

As for api layer, I've created JWT token, and used filterBefore that provides auth with given token
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);`

Now I have problem:

- token auth needs `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`
- web-view still need `JSESSIONID`

Ofcause api can be used such a way, but in final it uses `JSESSIONID` instead of token, so if I change token in `Authorization` header (for ex. using another user), it will still using credentials of previously authorized user.

Are there any abilities to make session be `STATELESS` for one group of endpoints (for ex: `/api/**`), and `ALWAYS` on other endpoints.
Or maybe there is any kind of possibility to make `@Controller` work with token-based auth?

Thatnk you for any ideas.

Comment: You can use JWT token for both.  For web view, you can store the JWT token in a cookie and get the JWT token from the cookie in a filter

Comment: How to get and append token from login form?

Comment: You store JWT token in Cookie after successful login and to get JWT from the Cookie by javascript on the web page and get the Cookie in the filter. here is link   https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/how-to-use-cookies-in-java-web-application